# Full screen doesn't work with object tag

Tags: fullscreen, object-tag

I have used fullscreen.js It's working fine on all platform when i use iframe but iframe is not properly working on iphone its automatically enlarging.
Then i tried object tag it's working fine with all the platforms but now my my fulscreen button is not working.I added allowfullscreen as well but does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can't go full screen on iOS web (Safari) as it is not allowed explicitly. You can do it with the meta tag but it might not be what you want from it. Here are some answers that might help

1. [Open webpage in fullscreen in Safari on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485919/open-webpage-in-fullscreen-in-safari-on-ios)
2. [How to get full screen mode with a mobile safari web app on IOS 8 Iphone 4S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547380/how-to-get-full-screen-mode-with-a-mobile-safari-web-app-on-ios-8-iphone-4s)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it was not working in my case.